# Rename multiple upload images

Tags: php

When I save multiple image rename into

```
a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg

a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg8f056d60fadf1619c2e63dbb5788ac3a.png
```

It duplication the frist one How to fix this

I want

```
a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg

8f056d60fadf1619c2e63dbb5788ac3a.png
```

Code

```
$target_path = ENV::$pathupload;
$img_tobaco = array_filter($_FILES['imgs']['name']);
$countFiles = count(array_filter($img_tobaco));

for($i = 0; $i <$countFiles; $i++){

  $file_name = $img_tobaco[$i];
  $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $ext = explode('.', basename($img_tobaco[$i]));
  $file_extension = end($ext);
  $img_name = md5(uniqid()).".".$ext[count($ext) - 1];
  $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).
  ".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
  $j = $j + 1; 
  if (in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgs']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { //if file moved to uploads folder
      echo $img_name."<br>";
    }else{
    }
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**

after I put $img_name = ""; inloops

when I echo $img_name It print

```
a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg

8f056d60fadf1619c2e63dbb5788ac3a.png
```

but in my folder name still look like this

```
a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg

    a362420af756a17c107702fd5fbf7c94.jpg8f056d60fadf1619c2e63dbb5788ac3a.png
```

here is my html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row input-with-icon data-img">
      <input type="file" id="send2" accept="image/*" class="form-control form-default form-image" placeholder="img" name="imgs[]">
      <label for="send-3" class="label-image">img</label>
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-with-icon data-img">
      <input type="file" id="send2" accept="image/*" class="form-control form-default form-image" placeholder="img" name="imgs[]">
      <label for="send-3" class="label-image">img</label>
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"></button>
<form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the value of `$img_name` for each interval by initializing it to empty string

```
$img_name = "";
$img_name = md5(uniqid()).".".$ext[count($ext) - 1];
```

Comment: edit your question and show what you have updated and also show you HTML form

Comment: i Updated my question

Comment: well i found it  thank you
I reset value $target_path